# creating a hidden directory on ansible

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

```yaml
- name: Creates directory
  become: yes
  become_user: marlon
  become_method: su
  file:
    path: "{{ homedir }}/.kube"
    state: directory
    owner: marlon
    group: wheel
    mode: 0775
    recurse: yes
```

Got the following task above, however keep getting the following error message:

```
"msg": "There was an issue creating {'cmd': ['echo', '~'], 'stdout': '/home/marlon', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.924421', 'end': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.927095', 'delta': '0:00:00.002674', 'changed': True, 'stdout_lines': [' as requested: [Errno 13] Permission denied: b\"{'cmd': ['echo', '~'], 'stdout': '/home/marlon', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.924421', 'end': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.927095', 'delta': '0:00:00.002674', 'changed': True, 'stdout_lines': ['\"",
"path": "{'cmd': ['echo', '~'], 'stdout': '/home/marlon', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.924421', 'end': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.927095', 'delta': '0:00:00.002674', 'changed': True, 'stdout_lines': ['/home/marlon'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}/.kube"
```

This is the ansible playbook that I ran:

```sh
marlon@ansible:~/.ansible$ ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts playbooks/settingup_kubernetes_cluster.yaml -e "ansible_sudo_pass:pass" -e "ansible_become_pass=pass" --tags masteronly -vvvv
```

Tried to scape the hidden directory using a `\` but nothing seems to work for me. Any suggestions or ideas? My inventory host files look like this:

```
[kubernetes-master-nodes]
master.madebeen.com ansible_host=192.168.153.135 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=marlon ansible_ssh_pass=test ansible_become_pass=test
[kubernetes-worker-nodes]
node1.madebeen.com ansible_host=192.168.153.136 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=marlon ansible_ssh_pass=Tar.Mid.Fun-456 ansible_become_pass=test
node2.madebeen.com ansible_host=192.168.153.137 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=marlon ansible_ssh_pass=Tar.Mid.Fun-456 ansible_become_pass=test
[node_and_workers:children]
kubernetes-master-nodes
kubernetes-worker-nodes
```

Comment: I 've also tried the following task getting the same output permission denied


    name: Setup kubeconfig for sudo user
    command: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
     - cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf "{{ homedir }}"/.kube/config
     - chown "{{ userid }}":"{{ groupnumber }}" "{{ homedir }}"/.kube/config

Comment: You probably don't have the permission to write in `/home/marlon`. Try to run a `find` command on the folder and see the rights this gives you. As a reminder of what right you need in order to create a directory, please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331908/165925

Comment: `{{ homedir }}` seems to be incorrect, try printing it to validate.

Comment: it does seem to be allowing the test command that you suggested as follow:

marlon@master:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for marlon:
root@master:~# find /home/marlon
/home/marlon
/home/marlon/0:00:00.002734,
/home/marlon/[],
/home/marlon/2021-09-30 08:32:30.405591,

Comment: also the debug seems to be printing the variable path correctly



TASK [setting_up_master : debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/marlon/.ansible/playbooks/roles/setting_up_master/tasks/main.yml:34
ok: [master.madebeen.com] => {
    "homedir": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": [
            "echo",
            "~"
        ],
        "stdout": "/home/marlon",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "/home/marlon"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message shows you, `{{ homedir }}` is not a `str`, it's `dict[str, Any]`:

> "path": "{'cmd': ['echo', '~'], 'stdout': '/home/marlon', 'stderr': '', 'rc': 0, 'start': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.924421', 'end': '2021-09-30 11:53:54.927095', 'delta': '0:00:00.002674', 'changed': True, 'stdout_lines': ['/home/marlon'], 'stderr_lines': [], 'failed': False}/.kube"

What I strongly suspect happened is you had `{ command: "echo ~", register: homedir }` and then just used `homedir` as if it was the output of `echo ~` but that's not the way ansible works

You'll at bare minimum want:

```yaml
   file:
    path: "{{ homedir.stdout }}/.kube"
```

and ideally you'd not depend upon running a shell command to find `marlon`'s home directory but rather either `{{ ansible_env.HOME }}` or read the value out of `/etc/passwd` on that machine

Comment: mdaniel you are a true legend buddy! thank you. the difference between ~ and $HOME is key here. thank you. using $HOME worked out perfectly!

Comment: just wondering where do you see this?
As the error message shows you, {{ homedir }} is not a str, it's dict[str, Any]:

Comment: `b\"{'cmd': ['e...` and the rest that follows right after `[Errno 13] Permission denied: `is actually the dict that the file module was expecting as a simple string